# How to position many divs horizontally without over wrapping

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm creating a horizontal ruler which is exactly as shown in this image: 
[image]

Image screenshot from here:
https://www.ladderlife.com/apply#SW5zdXJlZFBlcnNvbi5XZWlnaHQ=

Well, I'm looking to achieve horizontal calibrations with the help of divs. When I add divs and set them to display inline-block, the div goes to the next line upon reaching the full width of the parent.

I would like my divs to continue being in a horizontal line.

The idea is, the ruler is draggable and the parent container will be set to overflow hidden.

The calibration will start from 20 to 420, basically, you can see I need about 400 divs to be horizontally aligned.

This is my code

```js
$(function() {

  load_steps();

});


function load_steps() {
  var main_steps = "";
  for (var i = 20; i <= 420; i++) {
    main_steps += "<div class='main-step'><span>" + i + "</span></div>";;
  }

  $(".weight-ladder").html(main_steps);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

.horizontal-ladder {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.horizontal-ladder .main-step {
  width: 48px;
  border-left: 1px solid #979797;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>




<div class="weight-everything-holder">
  <div class="ui-widget horizontal-ladder">
    <div class="ui-widget-content weight-ladder">
      <!-- starting horizontal ruler -->



      <!-- ending the horizontal ruler -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I get out of my code:

[image]

Comment: `white-space:nowrap`....

Comment: inline-block will require white-space:nowrap on the parent to keep a single line, flex will require flex-shrink:0; on the children to avoid them shrinking ... ;) . float will wrap no matter

Comment: weight-ladder should be the flex container ;)